# My image with a PHP variable source is broken

Tags: javascript, php, html, image

My end goal is to have an image that swaps to a different image when the window scrolls past a certain point. I started with JavaScript to get the whole scroll position and set the if/else statement.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function checkHeight() {
        currentScrollPos = window.scrollY;

        if (currentScrollPos < 325)
            document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = "../wp-content/uploads/2017/04/LOGO-1.png";
        else if (currentScrollPos > 325)
            document.getElementById('test1').innerHTML = "../wp-content/uploads/2017/04/LOGO-1-alt.png";
    }
</script>

<p id="test1"></p>
```

All of that worked flawlessly. The inner HTML contents of the `<p id="test1"></p>` displayed the correct image source and swapped said source when I scrolled. Perfect.

Finally, I went to place that image source as the actual source of an `<img>` and that's where I hit a wall. I tried to use a simple PHP variable.

```
<?php
$src = <<<END
<p id="test1"></p>
END;
?>
```

And that worked. I could `echo` that `$src` and it displayed the image source correctly as before. So I proceeded, and I put it into the following code.

`<img src='<?php echo $src; ?>' />`

But nothing. It seems like it works to an extent except it's showing me a broken image symbol when I load up the page. Why is it not finding my image files? Am I missing something stupid?

Comment: A src attribute needs to contain just the URL. You're trying to put the p tag inside of the src attribute.

Comment: Go back to the [heredoc manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc); you've an (parse) error if that's your actual code with all those spaces before the closing identifier.

Comment: and why on earth are you using `<p>` as an `img` src?? what are you really trying to do here, make us go bonkers? *lol* Your code doesn't make any sense, IMHO.

Comment: What are the chances currentScrollPos would be 325? You will not get an id at that point.

Comment: All of the code works perfectly, except when placing the variable as the image source. That's the part I'm confused with and asking about

Comment: UPDATE: Nevermind. Realized I was being a moron and cut out the PHP part entirely. Thanks to everyone who tried to decipher wth I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The new, working code. Sorry about wasting all of your time and being a complete moron.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

function checkHeight() {
    currentScrollPos = window.scrollY;

    if (currentScrollPos < 325)
        document.getElementById('image').src = "../wp-content/uploads/2017/04/LOGO-1.png";
    else if (currentScrollPos > 325)
        document.getElementById('image').src = "../wp-content/uploads/2017/04/LOGO-1-alt.png";
}
</script>

<body onload="checkHeight();" onScroll="checkHeight();"></body>
    <img id="image" width="200px" />
```